# Appliance to wash or scrub fruit and vegetables? Washer or scrubber

Tags: equipment, vegetables, fruit

I need to wash or scrub 20 lb of oranges a day. Some have a layer of white stuff on them and I never tried juicing those without scrubbing. Does anyone know of a household sized  automated machine for this? The best I have found [Cuisine cleaner at AMZ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00124W0W4) seems intended for more delicate things. Will the ozone help in any way? Would ultrasonic? I hope I will not have to DIY something out of a paint buffer or back and forth towel mover machine.

Comment: I would just use my washing machine with a couple of dedicated towels to give them a bit of a scrub during agitation. Pull out the oranges a soon as they are not swimming, let the towels finish the spin cycle. Could that work?

Comment: Is the "white stuff" on the outside of the peels? What is your juicing method?

Comment: That link is more or a sanitizer.   I don't recall specifics but my dad sold supplies to fruit warehouses when I was a kid and they used a gentle agitated bath.   I think a washing machine would be too brutal but a washing machine works great for golf balls.

Comment: You could add add stiffer brush to this technique https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XY6I71-bajo . Or, you could be inspired by how Mandarin Oranges are processed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCD7Em5dYRM.

Comment: @Jolenealaska grime. 15$ white blackendecker spinning motion.

Comment: @Paulb That first link looks like it might be perfect. I will tell you tomorrow. Paparazzi  [I hope its like this](https://youtu.be/GYQWLyfcanA?list=LLj7P5V0-fPjw3WOTW0sMHyw&t=182) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RYo4fScDiTg) . The washing machine plan does not work because of a bunch of my circumstances.

Comment: Now THAT's what the "orange cleaner" products in the cleaning products aisle are for ;)

Comment: @Paulb https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8H4w9j4_bI there i made it

Comment: @ran8 : you're allowed to answer (and accept) your own question.  Besides what you did, you might want to mention what you like or don't like about it (eg, improvements you might try in a later version, tweaks you had to make to get it working for what you needed, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how sticky this coating is ...

Can you construct a huge wire tub (basket) and then hose them down with the garden hose outside?

My husband suggested created opposite rotating brushes where they enter at a slope and roll out after being brushed and washed at the same time.  It depends upon how much work space you have.

Comment: First suggestion is not really an option. Second suggestion could work but I would need more details as I am not really a handyman.

Answer (score 1):

PaulB suggested video [Crazy Russian's drill and brush potato washer.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XY6I71-bajo) I tried it. [My version.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8H4w9j4_bI) I bought a 12 Qt bucket and toilet brush. I sawed off the brush handle and drilled in the sawed end using a small bit. That eventually came out but the next one I used wide flatish bit did not. This method works but has problems.

Now I put the fruit in the bucket and scrub with 1.20$ shower scrub gloved hands.

The water always sploshed out and I do not know where to buy a cover with a hole for the bucket. Depending on time and pressure soft spots in oranges would be dug out. However, at the same time, citrien oil in the rind would be removed as well and that is a very good thing. The process so far takes some concentration. It also does not work on more than 3 pounds at a time. Without refinement this process is not significantly better for me than bucket-and-scrub-gloves. It needs a bigger bucket, bucket cover, and a scrub-like surface on the inside of the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Hanabishi wash machines are good for this. Buy the one with the round cloth opening. Buy one round baking rack with feet,legs to place in bottom. These are not agitation machines but the ones with the water movers in the bottom. So need rack to fit over them or damage to fruit. Add fruit, add water, add soap?, set to soft wash. Set timer. Turn on. Once cycle is done drain. If soap used next refill machine with water. set timer, turn on for rinse. Drain remove fruit. You can also wash your cloths in them. Look under Japan appliances not American. Hanabishi seem to hold up well. Very simple wiring, most switches can be replaced with toggle switches if they break. Safety with a stout cord & such. Machines not made for the American market so will need to order to there.